# Jmeter not accepting data within single quotes

Tags: api, post, parameters, jmeter

I have a requirement which involves me to send parameters with request. It is a POST request. I wish to send 2 parameters which are of the format `'5/12/2012 12:01:12 -0500'` , but Jmeter's View result tree is giving an error that the data was not entered.

What is the correct format that I should send the data in?
I tried without the single quotes, with double quotes, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raw Post Body data was accepted.

Comment: Are you answering your or question or are you adding info to it? Be more verbose!